# Sharepoint 365: Set the site contents page as the home page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Is there a way to set the home/landing page for a SharePoint 365 site to the Site Contents page https://support.office.com/en-us/article/The-SharePoint-Site-Contents-page-ba495c1e-00f4-475d-97c7-b518d546566b

Answer (score 1):

You could add a script on startpage in a script editor web part that redirect users to Site contents. That redirect surely will create a "flicker".This should do it:

```
window.location.href = "/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx";
```

Beware that this will be hard to remove from the web part (you will always get redirected), so maybe it should be added to a new page layout that is used by the startpage. Then it's possible to edit/remove the redirect through SharePoint Designer.

You could also try (if you have publishing feature activated) the "Welcome Page" link in site settings. Maybe there you could somehow point out the path to site contents, but I doubt it.

Comment: I tried the "welcome page" link in site settings but no joy.

Comment: Alright, then I believe that a redirect with script is your only option.